# Graph API token not working on EC2

Tags: api, curl, oauth, https, amazon-ec2

I am having a weird issue. I have a simple code that gets an auth token from an OAuth API for a social platform called Mixi. Afterwards, I am using simple curl with PHP to fetch a user's profile data etc. once the permission is granted. 
But, the issue is that it is working perfectly fine on any normal hosting with PHP e.g. on GoDaddy etc. but my project requires it to be eventually on Amazon EC2 Windows based server, which I am not really familiar with; but I have ensured that PHP works fine there and application pages are being served correctly.

The fact that code is working fine on other hosting servers suggests that code is correct. But, on Amazon; from the very first curl exec, am getting no auth token. I have tried to re-generate the API consumer secret several times.

I have even re-set Windows system time to match the same timezone. One additional info which I feel is relevant is that the API URLs are all https... Am not sure if that's causing any issues. Do I need to setup something special on Amazon EC2 Windows server to be able to fetch correctly using cURL from the social network's API ?

Please let me know if you want me to provide any additional info but it is confusing, because the exact same code of my application works on 2 different normal hosting providers that I access via cPanel and am getting token and required profile data in JSON response there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long fight, here is the solution:

To run HTTPS via cURL on Amazon EC2 a separate certificate file is needed to be included. This can be downloaded from here:

```
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
```

After this, the way to add this in PHP code before cURL call is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cacert.pem');
```

where $ch is curl handler (return value of curl_init() call). I hope this helps anyone who faces the same issue of not being able to run https fetch from API on EC2. 
Am still not sure, why the same code works on Godaddy or any normal hosting, probably they include this certificate for us themselves and hence we can directly call https from cURL.